# Google Oauth Cross-client Identity android (com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown)

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I am trying to get a token from my android app in order to exchange it later on my server for a refresh token. I followed the following guide 'https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth' and tried the following:

GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getContext(), "somegooglemail@gmail.com", "oauth2:server:client_id:" + myServerClientId + ":api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")

somegooglemail@gmail.com is my personnal mail and I am testing on my mobile phone so no problem from this side. The "myServerClientId" has the value defined from the Google developper console (i have create a native application and taken the id of this application). The two applications (my android and my native appliaction are of course in the same developper project in the developper console).
I am getting this all the time:

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
```

Does anybody has an idea? By the way I can obtain normal token when only specifying the scope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the problem. It is linked to the type of my server application. I have use "Native appliaction installed" like I saw in some post and it is necessary to use "Web appliaction" to make it works. Hope it will help someone...